# Can't install debian header 3.12-1-686-pae

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, headers

I'm trying to use virtualbox who need linux header but I can't found mine.

```
sudo apt-get -y install linux-headers-`uname -r`  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-3.12-1-686-pae
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.12-1-686-pae'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-3.12-1-686-pae'
```

I've tried adding the good repo

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

And after an apt-get update

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') virtualbox
```

Like mention [here](https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_.22Jessie.22_.28testing.29) without success.

After a `dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`

```
Loading new virtualbox-4.3.14 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.12-1-686-pae
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
[ ok ] Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules.
[FAIL] Starting VirtualBox kernel modules[....] No suitable module for running kernel found ... failed!
 failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"jessie" is also known as "testing". That means that things can change all the time.

The kernel version you have installed is no longer available in the repository; hence also the support packages such as linux-headers-* are also gone.

I recommend upgrading to the current linux-image package (linux-image-3.14-2-686-pae at time of writing), also install the corresponding linux-header package at the same time and then (after rebooting into the new kernel) you should be able to build the required virtualbox modules.

Comment: Just updated my kernel. Works a charm. Thanks